# Natbib citations do not work

Tags: natbib

After researching this problem I could not find any solutions so I have had to resort to asking it myself.

The problem is that citations are not working at all when using natbib. I have done the following:

**Bibliography.bib** file with a sample bib code:

```
@article{Reference1,
Abstract = {We have developed an enhanced Littrow configuration extended cavity diode laser (ECDL) that can be tuned without changing the direction of the output beam. The output of a conventional Littrow ECDL is reflected from a plane mirror fixed parallel to the tuning diffraction grating. Using a free-space Michelson wavemeter to measure the laser wavelength, we can tune the laser over a range greater than 10 nm without any alteration of alignment.},
Author = {C. J. Hawthorn and K. P. Weber and R. E. Scholten},
Journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
Month = {December},
Number = {12},
Numpages = {3},
Pages = {4477--4479},
Title = {Littrow Configuration Tunable External Cavity Diode Laser with Fixed Direction Output Beam},
Volume = {72},
Url = {http://link.aip.org/link/?RSI/72/4477/1},
Year = {2001}}
```

I then created a test tex file:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Content

test.  \citet{Reference1}  \cite{Reference1} \citet*{1.01} \citet{Reference2}       \citet{Reference3} 

\label{Bibliography}


\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the    Bibliography
%\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{Bibliography} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the         file named "Bibliography.bib"

\end{document}
```

Yet still the output is as follows:

[image: Bibliography working half correctly (no ennumeration) while citations do not work]

As per the above figure, you may notice that even the enumeration in the bibliography is not working correctly.

**What could be the problem please ?**

Test Project Contents: *Bibliography.bib, test.tex.* Moreover, I am using Latexian

LOG:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/Users/Wiltabone/Desktop/Test/TSWLatexianTemp_000017.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty) (./TSWLatexianTemp_000017.aux)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Reference1' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Reference1' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `1.01' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Reference2' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Reference3' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.

(./TSWLatexianTemp_000017.bbl
Underfull \hbox (badness 1102) in paragraph at lines 23--28
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Carl E. Wie-man and Leo Holl-berg.  Us-ing diode lasers for atomic
)

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./TSWLatexianTemp_000017.aux

Package natbib Warning: Citation(s) may have changed.
(natbib)                Rerun to get citations correct.
```

Thanks

Comment: Run it first through latex, then bibtex, then latex again.

Comment: I think I tried that once with the terminal, however I am unsure how to do the steps when using a software package such as Latexian.

Comment: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: The the last item of the FAQ http://tacosw.com/latexian/support.php discusses this.  I presume the installation has concrete help on this matter.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be about issues not related to the points raised in the posting itself.